# Is there a single point-of-reference that lists the release dates for the Live Communications Server (and other related client/server applications)

Tags: windows, lync, skype, ms-office-communicator

Whilst I've been able to find historic information relating to the Live Communications Server (and subsequent versions as it was rebranded), what I haven't been able to find is a definitive list of the release dates for both the client/server applications of the following:

Live Communications Server 2003

Live Communications Server 2005

Office Communicator 2007

Lync 2010

Lync 2013

Skype for Business 2015

Skype for Business 2016

Skype for Business 2019

Does such a list exist, or is there a single place that lists the release dates for these applications?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft publishes this information on their Support Lifecycle page.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/?terms=Live%20Communications%20Server

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/?terms=Office%20Communicator

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/?terms=Lync

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/?terms=Skype%20for%20Business

Answer (score 0):

When Wikipedia does not provide a definitive answer (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_Communications_Server_2005 only lists the obvious **2005** but no exact date)
I would search the [Microsoft press releases](https://news.microsoft.com) for announcements.

That should result in press releases such as:

> **REDMOND, Wash., May 4, 2004** — Microsoft Corp. today announced the opening of the **beta program** for Microsoft®
> Office Live Communications Server 2005, previously code-named “Vienna.
> ...
> https://news.microsoft.com/2004/05/04/microsoft-unveils-live-communications-server-2005/

and

> **REDMOND, Wash., Oct. 26, 2004** — Microsoft Corp. today announced the **release to manufacturing (RTM)** of Microsoft®
> Office Live Communications Server 2005.
> ...
> https://news.microsoft.com/2004/10/26/microsoft-delivers-microsoft-office-live-communications-server-2005/

etc.

When you're feeling generous you should give back to the community and update the Wikipedia articles with the results you find.